# create ArrayList with method and parameter is ArrayList's name

Tags: java, arraylist

my question is simple, but haven't found answer anywhere, how can I create array like this:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result_of_query_into_array(
        ArrayList<String> nameofArray) {

    nameofArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        while (result.next()) {

            nameofArray.add(result.getString("nombre_estadio"));
            nameofArray.add(result.getString("ciudad"));
            nameofArray.add(result.getString("capacidad"));
            nameofArray.add(result.getString("temperatura"));
            nameofArray.add(result.getString("equipos"));

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Error en result.next().print..: " + e);
    }

    ARRAY_PRINCIPAL_MULTIDIMENSIONAL.add(nameofArray);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "got all rows  from table  ");

    return ARRAY_PRINCIPAL_MULTIDIMENSIONAL;

}
```

so when i use this method i have to do this :

```
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();

obj.result_ofquery_into_array(myArray);
```

is  it posible   to just  do something like :

```
obj.result_of_query_into_array(myarrayWithoutInstantiatingOutside);
```

when i put just the name of the array i get an error :

```
myarrayWithoutInstantiatingOutside cannot be resolved to a variable
```

please help,  thanks

Comment: Why can't you instantiate outside not within ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you are passing a variable as an argument, you are in fact passing the reference of an object, which is then used. When not initializing a variable, you are passing and empty reference, which cannot be resolved. In your example, the correct way of doing this, since anyway you are overwriting the value of the variable, would be :

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> result_of_query_into_array() {

    ArrayList<String> nameOfArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Logic...

    return nameOfArray;

}
```

And then just do :

```
myarrayWithoutInstantiatingOutside = obj.result_of_query_into_array();
```

Then, you are instantiating the object inside the method, and then returning the reference.

### Variables

You have to see variables as simple adresses. Let's take, for example, a house on a street.

`123 StackOverflow street`

Now, this address, for you, might be your friend's address :

`Adress myFriendAddress = 123 StackOverflow street`

But for someone else, it might be his boss's address :

`Adress myBossAddress = 123 StackOverflow street`

The physical position of the house is the same, but the reference is different. It is the same way with objects and variables. The object has a memory address which is the physical position of the object in your memory.

Comment: well yes,  actually i haven't thought of it that way and it does make sence,  thanks,  but   lets  say  i want this to be the way  i create  eg:   a new  player,   but  this would be comming from `JTextField PLAYER = new JTextField(nameofplayer);`,  and name of player would be then  used  to create the    array, something like :


    `result_of_query_into_array( PLAYER )`  in which case player would be created,   

ps:   just creating it out of my head something like a  WHAT IF ... 


@Gladhus